# Vim save highlight info screen to file

Tags: vim

Is there a way in Vim to save the window that comes up if you type `:highlight`? I'm working on a color scheme and it would be helpful to be able to have a copy of it open in a real window (so I can search, or delete lines once I've taken care of them in my color scheme). I've already tried `:h :highlight`, which doesn't turn up anything useful, but surely there must be a way. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`redir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3aredir) to redirect the output of highlight to a file.

In vim you run

```
:redir > file
:highlight
:redir END
```

file should now contain the output of highlight.

**Update**: One way to highlight the `xxx` in the highlight file is to run the function below

```
function! HiFile()
    let i = 1
    while i <= line("$")
        if strlen(getline(i)) > 0 && len(split(getline(i))) > 2
            let w = split(getline(i))[0]
            exe "syn match " . w . " /\\(" . w . "\\s\\+\\)\\@<=xxx/"
        endif
        let i += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

The function uses `syn match` to match the highlight group with the `xxx` after it.

You can place the function in your vimrc and then to run it type `:call HiFile()` while in the highlight file.

Comment: Righteous! I'd never seen `:redir` before. I accepted this (since it's exactly what I asked for), but I don't suppose there's any way to get the output file to actually display the highlighting as well? Some syntax setting perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelM. There might be away but I'm not sure. You might be able to write a vim script to highlight the `xxx` properly. I would take a look at the file at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`

Comment: @MichaelM. Look at the edited answer to highlight the `xxx` part of the highlight output.

Answer (score 4):

There's a menu command *Syntax > Highlight Test* that creates a buffer with all highlight groups. Alternatively, you can trigger it via

```
:runtime syntax/hitest.vim
```